# '09 corolla dim lights not working

Tags: electrical, toyota, headlight, corolla

On the car the dim/bright works on the driver side, but on the passenger side the dim doesn't work but the bright does. I have tried 2 new lights with no avail.

Comment: Have you checked for burnt fuses?  Frequently the fuses are split left and right so that you don't lose all light if the fuse blows.

Comment: The dim/bright works on the driver side but only the bright works on the passenger side

Comment: Is this still a problem you are trying to resolve? If not, can you tell us what fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

## Check for a burnt fuse

It is quite possible that the fuse is blown.  Frequently, the fuses are split side to side so that if the fuse for the left light blows or you get a short in the left light circuit, you won't lose all your light while you're driving.

My recommendation is that you check for blown fuses.  Look at your electrical diagram and see which fuse goes with the right side.  If replacing the fuse doesn't help, check for circuit continuity and resistance.

**Edit:**

After further research, it appears that the issue probably lies under fuse 15 in this diagram:

[image]

(Courtesy of [autogenius.info](http://www.autogenius.info/toyota-corolla-mk10-10th-generation-2009-2011-fuse-box-diagram/))

It's a 10 amp fuse, and I suspect it's blown.  Replace it.